# Does the "Leibniz multicategory over $R$" have an accepted name?

Tags: calculus, commutative-algebra, terminology, multilinear-algebra, differential-algebra

Let $R$ denote a commutative ring.

> **Definition.** The "Leibniz multicategory" over $R$ is given as follows:
>
> *Objects.* $R[D]$-modules (where $D$ is a formal symbol; an 'indeterminate').
>
> *Multiarrows.* $R$-multilinear functions satisfying the "Leibniz Law." For example, if we're given an $R$-multilinear function $f : X, Y \rightarrow Z$, the Leibniz law reads:
>
> $$Df(x,y) = f(Dx,y) + f(x,Dy)$$
>
> The $n=3$ case is:
>
> $$Df(x,y,z) = f(Dx,y,z) + f(x,Dy,z)+f(x,y,Dz)$$
>
> etc.

For illustration purposes, lets show that if we're given multiarrows $$f : X,Y \rightarrow J, \quad g : J,Z \rightarrow K,$$ then the function $$h : X,Y,Z \rightarrow K \quad x,y,z \mapsto g(f(x,y),z)$$ is also a multiarrow.

We have:

$$Dh(x,y,z) = Dg(f(x,y),z) = g(Df(x,y),z)+g(f(x,y),Dz)$$

But

$$g(Df(x,y),z) = g(f(Dx,y)+f(x,Dy),z) = g(f(Dx,y),z)+g(f(x,Dy),z)$$

So

$$Dh(x,y,z) = g(f(Dx,y),z)+g(f(x,Dy),z)+g(f(x,y),Dz)$$

In other words:

$$Dh(x,y,z) = h(Dx,y,z)+h(x,Dy,z)+h(x,y,Dz)$$

as required.

*Motivation.* A differential $R$-algebra with one derivation is just a monoid object in the above multicategory. The obvious variant of the above multicategory to many $D's$ gives us differential algebras with many derivations.

> **Question.** Does this multicategory (and/or its obvious generalizations) have an accepted name?
>
> If not, is there at least somewhere I can learn more about it?

Comment: From the algebra $A$ and a derivation $D$ you can construct the Ore extension $A[X;D]$. Modules over $A[X;D]$ are an analogue of vector bundles with a connection, in a way, and you can tensor them. Maybe that is a more traditional setting in which yo can do wha you want